# How To Run Both JS And Python In Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am looking to run both python cloud functions and JS cloud functions side by side. Also I want to be able to run these in my local emulator when doing dev work. Are both of these scenarios possible? If so how would I run both of them in the emulator? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started).  If you have a more specific question about what you have read there, please post the specifics of where you are stuck with that, or what's not working the way you expect.